# Grafana query parsing error with label_values

Tags: couchdb, grafana, grafana-templating, exporter, grafana-variable

There are two CouchDB servers and I am using variable in Grafana to visualize some metrics, issue is query with variable end up with wrong prasing:

```
couchdb_server_node_info{instance="10\\.10\\.10\\.199:9984"}
```

I do not why it includes the slash, that leads to empty result. am I using correct query "label_values"?

Here is my variable setting, which the result shows two servers:

[image]

and here is how I use it:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is fixed! I had to disable `Include All Option`